# How to set focus to a TextBox after its Text has been set through binding?

Tags: wpf, focus, selectall

I am trying to implement SelectAll (text) functionality for all TextBoxes in my WPF application. I found how to do that [here](http://www.intertech.com/Blog/post/How-to-Select-All-Text-in-a-WPF-Content-on-Focus.aspx). However, the first TextBox on my form is not automatically focused. I try to remedy that in the Window_Loaded eventhandler by simply using `firstTextBox.Focus`. That works, but the Text property of this TextBox is set through binding and it seems that this happens *after* the Window_Loaded event. So, I end up with a first textbox that is initially focused, but has not its Text selected. It seems I need to hook up to a different Event. Which one?

Comment: can you add some information/code for your binding and wether you use mvvm or codebehind. without this information i would say simply set the focus after you set the datacontext.

Comment: @blindmeis: too simple for me to think about that ;-) It works! Make youe comment into an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you try DataContextChangedEvent. Bringing focus is always a pain in WPF... we have to relay on code behind file for it...

Answer (score 1):

Try using FocusManager in the XAML of your window:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
    Title="MainWindow"
    FocusManager.FocusedElement="{Binding ElementName=firstTextBox}">
    <Grid>
        <TextBox Name="firstTextBox" />
    </Grid>
 </Window>
```

Comment: No luck, The first TextBox gets focus allright, but its text is assigned afterwards.